# rectangular and triangular commutative diagram with curves

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, overleaf, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Here is the diagram I want to draw:

> [image]

Could anyone help me in drawing it please?

the curved arrows and the diagonal arrows, I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Did you try something already? Please share a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/204164) to help us help you. Your previous question has been answered, you could learn a bit from that in order to produce a functionnal `tikzcd` graph.

Comment: Yeah I know how to draw a part of the diagram @SebGlav I will update my post with it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You still don't have a working example. You need `\usepackage{tikz-cd}`. Which diagonal and curved arrows do you want? Your example is nothing like your hand-drawn picture.

Comment: Ok, let me correct it, sorry.@SandyG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curved arrows can be made using `bend left` or `bend right`. Use `ur` in the `\arrow` command to have the arrow point up one row and right one column. Similarly, `uurr` will go up 2 rows and right two columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
 & & D_{c(f)}\\
R\arrow[r] & \pi_{\alpha}D_{\alpha}\arrow[r,yshift=2pt,"c"]\arrow[r,yshift=-2pt,"d"']\arrow[ur]\arrow[d] & \pi_fD_{c(f)}\arrow[d]\arrow[u,"\pi_f"']\\
C\arrow[r]\arrow[rr, bend right,"F"']\arrow[ur]\arrow[u,dashed,"\exists!"]\arrow[uurr,bend left,"F"] & D\arrow[r] & E
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I need to reverse all the directions of the arrows?

Comment: @Idonotknow: You can use `dl` for "down-left". Similarly `ddll` is "down-down-left-left". Or you can add `[arrows=<-]` after `\begin{tikzcd}`.

Comment: @Idonotknow I strongly suggest that you read the `tikz-cd` manual where you would find many very intersting informations about how to draw those (relatively) simple graphs.